# C# websocket client using websock4net

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket4net

I need some samples C# codes to make client program like

1.When I click login button a function connect to binary.com using given api token and return balance in a label box in a form , ( sample codes here https://developers.binary.com/demos/ ) ,

2. Display a ticks streams in a box
3. when I click buy button a buy trade will execute in binary.com and result should display in a label all samples in (https://developers.binary.com/api/#transaction)
4. Need use websocket4net package its uses to make socket open until we close 
   I can build a using the sample codes of the above request

Comment: I think you should try yourself and then come back with specific questions, rather than just posting your "requirements".

Comment: Yes after 20 hrs of reading , i found solution thanks anyway

Comment: any code samples which you can share?

Comment: Hi SSoftware Do  you have a code sample you share or give direction where you found help how implent the API with websocke4net.